# How do I get a list of all the serial ports on my computer?

Tags: mvvm, combobox, serial-port

I want to binding available `SerialPort` to combobox in MVVM, so I have this:

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_PortName" ItemsSource="{Binding PortsList}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPort}" DisplayMemberPath="PortNames"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
    public ObservableCollection<SerialPort> PortsList{ get; set; }

    private SerialPort _selectedPort; 
    public SerialPort SelectedPort 
    { 
       get { return _selectedPort; } 
       set
       {
          _selectedPort = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPort"); 
       }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
       DefaultValue_Load();
    }

    public void DefaultValue_Load()
    {
        //what should I do
        PortsList = new ObservableCollectioin<SerialPort>();
    }
}
```

So what should I do to binding the serialport to combobox? Thanks!

Comment: What's your problem? Are you asking how to get all the serial ports on the computer?  Which has nothing to do with MVVM or combo boxes...

Comment: I can't get all the serial ports by the object `PorsList` in the code above. I want to binding the PortsList to combobox.

Comment: Can you get a list of all serial ports on the computer?

Comment: By the current code, no.

Comment: You can't figure out how to use this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx